# Google Apps Script Drawings/Buttons won't display without refreshing page

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a number of Google Spreadsheets containing several sheets, each of which have buttons (drawings) with Google Apps Script assigned to them. These buttons do simple things like add a row, sort a range or navigate to another sheet.

I have just updated my laptop - still using Google Chrome but every time I open a sheet, the buttons don't display so I now have to refresh the page to get them to display. Other users of the same sheet don't have this problem. Is there a setting I need to change?

Comment: Hi ! Do these buttons never work the first time you open the Spreadsheet? Do they always work when you refresh? Could you try this on incognito to see if the same issue occurs? Thanks ! :D

Comment: When the buttons are visible and I click them, they always do exactly what I want them to do. It's just that every time I go into a sheet they are not there so I refresh the page and they become visible and functional. I go to another sheet within the same spreadsheet and go back to the sheet I just refreshed and the buttons have disappeared again. Every time I go to a sheet (within any spreadsheet) with buttons in it, I have to refresh the page to make the buttons reappear.

Comment: I changed Chrome to Incognito Mode and navigated from sheet to sheet and the buttons appear every time however, I don't want to work in Incognito Mode

Comment: Also, on this new laptop, I am using the same google account as my previous laptop where the buttons displayed every time. I have not changed and chrome or google settings on my new laptop.

Comment: If I leave the sheet open and don't refresh, the buttons never become visible. They only appear when I refresh the screen. I added a refresher extension to Chrome and that worked but it made the screen flash, the button would appear and disappear and reappear - I couldnt work with it so removed the extension.

Comment: Hi ! This could be an issue with one of your Chrome extensions. It could also help to clear all cookies and cache (you will have to login again). Could you please clear your cache and cookies following [this guide](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) and let me know if after login again the behaviour persists? Thanks ! :D

Comment: Thank you - that worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these type of behaviours happen where your Spreadsheet works fine on an incognito window but not on a normal window they are most likely due to a Chrome extension or a cookies problem.

To solve this behaviour it usually helps to clear all cookies and cache (you will need to login again) and if that does not work you can also try to disable your Chrome extensions to check if any of them are messing with the Spreadsheet.

You can achieve this in Chrome following [this guide](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).